# How to define a float array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, floating-point

I am working a debian 7, using gcc.

I initialize a test vector as follows:

```
float test_vec[] = {4.31,3.33,1.58,0.75,7.82,1.85,0.45,0.11,0.98,3.45};
```

The `sizeof()` function applied to this vector returns 40.

I use a for() to printf each element and most of them are zero or very large positive/negative numbers.

How I should define the `test_vector` in order to get the right size?

Comment: _"I use a for() to printf each element"_ You should probably add that code to your question.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the amount of bytes, if you want to know how many elements use `sizeof(test_vec) / sizeof(test_vec[0])`

Comment: This is an array, not a vector. `std::vector` is a template container class in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Michael

Comment: Thanks for the comment @iksemyonov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the array *in bytes* not the number of elements. If you want the number of elements you need to e.g. `sizeof(float_vec) / sizeof(float_vec[0])`.

Note that this "trick" only works on actual arrays, once the array has decayed to a pointer (for example what happens when you pass the array as an argument to a function) then it will no longer work as the `sizeof` operator then gives you the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

Comment: There's no good strategy with a pointer.  Once you pass a pointer somewhere you can only obtain the size of the pointer rather than the memory it points to.  It is up to you to keep track of how much stuff you're pointing at.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHoelzer

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
float test_vec[] = {4.31,3.33,1.58,0.75,7.82,1.85,0.45,0.11,0.98,3.45};
size_t size = (sizeof(test_vec)/sizeof(*test_vec));
printf("%zu\n", size);
```

This outputs 10.

Comment: Edited, question is tagged C (not C++)